# com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hikaricp

I got to know about HikariCP so was giving it a try but got this exception while running. couldn't find what is the root cause. Anyone has any idea how to fix it ?

I am just siply insering id, name to a person table using jdbcteplate batchupdate.

```xml
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
        <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="30" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />

        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</prop>
                <prop key="user">TEST</prop>
                <prop key="password">TEST</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
     <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
          <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
    </bean>

    <bean id="HikariCpSample" class="com.ignite.sample.clustering.HikariCpSample">  
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property> 
    </bean>​
```

**Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]:** Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: **ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `connectionTestQuery` property value should be a valid SQL, For Oracle use `SELECT 1 from dual`. Change it to:

```
   <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 from dual" />
```